# Rearrange a file excel of strings with R

Tags: r, xls

I have a xls file like that:

[image]

I would like to write a R code to rearrange it, e.g. in the following way

[image]

The example shows only the first row of original file xls, but the same applies also for all the other rows.

Any suggestions please?

**EDIT.** reproducible example:

```
dput(head(myfile, 4))
```

`` structure(list(`{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates": 
    [669803.015640121,5123442.04315501]},"properties":{"SCODE":"89940PG","NAME_D":"ETSCH BEI SALURN","NAME_I":"ADIGE A SALORNO","NAME_L":"ETSCH BEI SALURN","NAME_E":"ETSCH BEI SALURN","ALT":210,"LONG":11.20262,"LAT":46.243333}}` = c("{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[626295.144332811,5164467.60475602]},\"properties\":{\"SCODE\":\"08155PG\",\"NAME_D\":\"ETSCH BEI EYRS\",\"NAME_I\":\"ADIGE A ORIS\",\"NAME_L\":\"ETSCH BEI EYRS\",\"NAME_E\":\"ETSCH BEI EYRS\",\"ALT\":873.99,\"LONG\":10.64963,\"LAT\":46.621876}}", 
"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[744723.350800056,5192575.70046406]},\"properties\":{\"SCODE\":\"45200SF\",\"NAME_D\":\"Gsies Pfinnalm\",\"NAME_I\":\"Casies Malga Pfinn\",\"NAME_L\":\"Gsies Pfinnalm\",\"NAME_E\":\"Gsies Pfinnalm\",\"ALT\":2152,\"LONG\":12.2096,\"LAT\":46.8417}}", 
"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[688387.444866793,5165389.11604176]},\"properties\":{\"SCODE\":\"82500WS\",\"NAME_D\":\"Rittnerhorn\",\"NAME_I\":\"Corno del Renon\",\"NAME_L\":\"Rittnerhorn\",\"NAME_E\":\"Rittnerhorn\",\"ALT\":2260,\"LONG\":11.4604,\"LAT\":46.6156}}", 
"{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[743964.273827689,5194147.3777763]},\"properties\":{\"SCODE\":\"45100WS\",\"NAME_D\":\"Gsies Regelspitze\",\"NAME_I\":\"Casies Cima Regola\",\"NAME_L\":\"Gsies Regelspitze\",\"NAME_E\":\"Gsies Regelspitze\",\"ALT\":2747,\"LONG\":12.2005,\"LAT\":46.8561}}"
)), .Names = "{\"type\":\"Feature\",\"geometry\":{\"type\":\"Point\",\"coordinates\":[669803.015640121,5123442.04315501]},\"properties\":{\"SCODE\":\"89940PG\",\"NAME_D\":\"ETSCH BEI SALURN\",\"NAME_I\":\"ADIGE A SALORNO\",\"NAME_L\":\"ETSCH BEI SALURN\",\"NAME_E\":\"ETSCH BEI SALURN\",\"ALT\":210,\"LONG\":11.20262,\"LAT\":46.243333}}", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")) ``

Comment: Hi can you use `dput( head( YOURDATA, 3))` to give us data to work with rather than the image.

Comment: Thank you @TylerRinker, I modified my post. I did not know ```dput```, I hope my code is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are likely way better tidyverse answers to this problem but this works on the data set you're after.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(dplyr)

lapply(myfile[[1]], function(elem) {
    fromJSON(elem) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
        group_by(type) %>%
        summarize_all(function(x) if (length(unique(x))== 1 ) x[1] else paste0('[', paste(x, collapse = ', '), ']'))
}) %>%
    bind_rows() %>%
    setNames(gsub('^[^.]+\\.', '', colnames(.)))

##   type    type  coordinates                          SCODE   NAME_D            NAME_I             NAME_L            NAME_E              ALT  LONG   LAT
##   <fct>   <fct> <chr>                                <chr>   <chr>             <chr>              <chr>             <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 Feature Point [626295.144332811, 5164467.60475602] 08155PG ETSCH BEI EYRS    ADIGE A ORIS       ETSCH BEI EYRS    ETSCH BEI EYRS     874.  10.6  46.6
## 2 Feature Point [744723.350800056, 5192575.70046406] 45200SF Gsies Pfinnalm    Casies Malga Pfinn Gsies Pfinnalm    Gsies Pfinnalm    2152   12.2  46.8
## 3 Feature Point [688387.444866793, 5165389.11604176] 82500WS Rittnerhorn       Corno del Renon    Rittnerhorn       Rittnerhorn       2260   11.5  46.6
## 4 Feature Point [743964.273827689, 5194147.3777763]  45100WS Gsies Regelspitze Casies Cima Regola Gsies Regelspitze Gsies Regelspitze 2747   12.2  46.9
```